# Error in making a bootable USB drive

Tags: usb-drive, macosx

I was trying to make a bootable USB drive but nothing seems to work. I don't think I need to explain a lot here because I think the picture speaks for itself.

[image]

Comment: Btw, i am trying to install lubuntu on my mac but i am not really an expert on this field

Comment: I see inconsistency in your commands. what is the name of your device? I guess the right name is `/dev/rdisk1s1` if so, just run this: `sudo dd if=... of=/dev/rdisk1s1 bs=1m` (note: not capital m)

Comment: It may be version of dd. See these instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

I think before you execute the dd command. You should execute the lsblk command to see which drive your USB is located. After that, you can do what you have just done. However, this time, try with the following style:

sudo dd bs=4M if=path/to/your/*.img of=/dev/sdx (x is the letter of your drive) && sync

Edit: This method will only work on Linux, so you have to do it in another way for Macintosh.

1. diskutil list > list out all the drive in your system.
2. diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN > identify your device and unmount it (In your case, I believe that drive is /dev/disk1)
3. sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1M

Comment: lsblk command? I am really new to this.

Comment: I am new to all of this too. My best advice is to stick around and do not give up if you encounter a problem. lsblk will list you all the drive in your system. By doing this, you will be able to indicate which drive your USB is on.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about everything that I have said. Please check my edited answer again.

Comment: Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful                                   Brukers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ bruker$ sudo dd if=/path/to/Users/bruker/Desktop/Lubuntu.img of=/dev/disk1s1 bs=1m
dd: /path/to/Users/bruker/Desktop/Lubuntu.img: No such file or directory
Brukers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ bruker$

Comment: For annyone trying the same, burn the downloaded ISO file to a cd. This is much easyer. Thanks to all the people who healped me.